# Akward Proguard error on new (blank) project

Tags: android, proguard

After creating new android project I just put the name and package name... and nothing else

then in the project.properties I add

> proguard.config=proguard-project.txt

then if I try to export signed apk I get this error

> [2013-09-19 12:05:57 - ProguardTest] Warning: there were 12 unresolved
>   references to classes or interfaces. [2013-09-19 12:05:57 -
>   ProguardTest]          You may need to specify additional library jars
>   (using '-libraryjars'). [2013-09-19 12:05:57 - ProguardTest] Warning:
>   there were 12 unresolved references to program class members.
>   [2013-09-19 12:05:57 - ProguardTest]          Your input classes
>   appear to be inconsistent. [2013-09-19 12:05:57 - ProguardTest]
>   You may need to recompile them and try again. [2013-09-19 12:05:57 -
>   ProguardTest]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the
>   option  [2013-09-19 12:05:57 - ProguardTest]
>   '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'. [2013-09-19 12:05:57 -
>   ProguardTest] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.

This is the strange part if I untick  "Android Private Libraries" on the Order and Export tab of the build path editor it just works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the details in the error log (before the quoted lines), you may need to add missing libraries, build against a more recent Android runtime, or just specify `-ignorewarnings` or `-dontwarn`.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced field/method '...' in program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)

Note that `proguard.config` in the file `project.properties` typically also points to a generic configuration file `proguard-android.txt` inside the Android SDK. The file `proguard-project.txt` then only needs to contain project-specific configuration.